# Mongoose/Mongo: Update Not Saving

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm extremely perplexed by this issue that I'm having with mongo/mongoose. I'm essentially trying to get an array of products, delete a certain product from the array, and then update the shopping chart with the new array that omits the selected product. Here's the snippet of code I'm dealing with:

```
const remove = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('here is the product id ' + req.body.cart.product)
  delete req.body._owner // disallow owner reassignment.
  Cart.find({_id: req.user.cartId})
  .then((products1) => {
    console.log("array of products: " + products1[0].product)
    const index = products1[0].product.indexOf(req.body.cart.product)
    console.log("index valeu: " + index)
    if (index > -1) {
      products1[0].product.splice(index, 1)
      return products1[0].product
    }
    return products1[0].product
  })
  .then((products2) => {
    console.log('Second Promise Input: ' + products2)
    Cart.update({_id: req.user.cartId}, {$set: {product: products2}})
  })
  .then(() => res.sendStatus(204))
  .catch(next)
  }
```

And here's the output from my server:

```
Server listening on port 4741
here is the product id 5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0
array of products: 5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0
index valeu: 0
Second Promise Input: 5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0,5952b57ea52d092b8d34c6b0
PATCH /carts-decrease/595b037e128cfd37e0c864d7 204 38.773 ms
```

According to my console.logs, I'm getting the array just the way I want it but it simply does not update the shopping cart with the new array. I've been staring at this code for far too long and I'd appreciate a second set of eyes on this. Thanks.

P.S. Ignore the fact that the product ids are all the same, its just a testing variable

Cart Schema:

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: Array,
    required: false
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
      const userId = (options.user && options.user._id) || false
      ret.editable = userId && userId.equals(doc._owner)
      return ret
    }
  }
})

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema)

module.exports = Cart
```

Product Schema:

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

module.exports = Product
```

Show request:

```
const show = (req, res) => {
  const product = {}
  product.array = []
//  console.log(req.cart.product)
  const promises = []

  Promise.all(req.cart.product.map(function (id) {
    return Product.find({_id: ObjectId(id)})
  })).then(function (products) {
    console.log(products)
    req.cart.product = products
    return res.json({
      cart: req.cart.toJSON({virtuals: true, user: req.user})
    })
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.sendStatus(500)
  })
}
```

Comment: Read [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: but wont pull remove all instances of that product id from the array? I'm trying to remove a specific product id that may appear multiple times in the array.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried using pull and it erases every instances of that product id. I remember you helped me about a week ago with a similar problem related to promises. Is that what's happening in my code above?

Comment: The `$pull` operator takes a query and does indeed remove all matched instances just like the documentation says. But you are "pulling" an `ObjectId` value from the array. They are all "unique", so if you simply apply the :"one" you need to remove from the array, then that is all that will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to slightly modify your `cartSchema` and store products in the form of an array of [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

```
const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    products: [{
        name: { type: String },
        price: { type: Number }
        ...
    }]
    ...
});
```

If you do this you can simply use the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) update operator to remove products from your cart:

```
{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }
```

In your case the query should then look like this:

```
Cart.update(
    { _id: req.user.cartId },
    { $pull: { products: { '_id': req.body.cart.product } }}
);
```

As the embedded documents will have their own ObjectId there will only be one document matching the query.

Comment: @sam-d Does this help you?

Comment: but wont pull remove all instances of that product id from the array? I'm trying to remove a specific product id that may appear multiple times in the array

Comment: or should I do a pull and then set? that might remedy the problem

Comment: It should just work fine with $pull. It is true that it removes all instances matching the query. But if I get your schema right the products of a cart should be an array of embedded documents. As such they should have an ObjectId (which is unique) so there should only be one match. If they are not an array of embedded documents I would recommend to refactor. It would also be helpful if you could post your Cart schema, then I can give you a more precise answer/example.

Comment: added it above^^

Comment: Can you include in a formatted way in your question, pls?

Comment: Added it to the post body, how does my schema look? This is my first mongoose/express/mongodb project sop any schema tips would be highly appreciated

Comment: Schema basically looks fine. What do you push inside the product array in the cart schema? Complete product objects?

Comment: Nope just the product id. The product information just added with a show request. I'll post it above

Comment: I would recommend you to push the complete product info in form of an embedded document. See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: I'll make another branch on my project and give it a shot. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Updated my answer to give you an example. If this helps you could accept my answer to your question pls :)

Comment: I would upvote it twice if I could but I don't have enough reputation points :/

Comment: I don't mean upvoting but accepting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks! Always happy if I can help out :)